# special chars in XML

Tags: c#, xml

I want to parse the following XML

```
XmlElement costCenterElement2 = doc.CreateElement("CostCenter");
costCenterElement2.InnerXml =
    "<CostCenterNumber>2</CostCenterNumber> <CostCenter>" +
    "G&A: Fin & Acctng" +
    "</CostCenter>";
```

but I found XML Exception

> An error occurred while parsing EntityName.

Comment: I updated my answer to clarify how to know when the problem is upstream and needs to be dealt with at the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        private string SanitizeXml(string source)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(source))
            {
                return source;
            }
            if (source.IndexOf('&') < 0)
            {
                return source;
            }
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(source);
            result = result.Replace("&lt;", "<>lt;")
                            .Replace("&gt;", "<>gt;")
                            .Replace("&amp;", "<>amp;")
                            .Replace("&apos;", "<>apos;")
                            .Replace("&quot;", "<>quot;");
            result = result.Replace("&", "&amp;");
            result = result.Replace("<>lt;", "&lt;")
                            .Replace("<>gt;", "&gt;")
                            .Replace("<>amp;", "&amp;")
                            .Replace("<>apos;", "&apos;")
                            .Replace("<>quot;", "&quot;");

            return result.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: @AZ nice idea, although this doesn't handle cases like `&#160;`, or non-character entities that have been defined in a document.

Comment: true. it's just a hack. but i don't think there is a proper solution to this. it might solve the OPs particular problem though.

Answer (score 7):

Yeah - a `&` is not valid in XML and needs to be escaped to `&amp;`.

The other characters invalid characters and their escapes:

- < - `&lt;`
- > - `&gt;`
- " - `&quote;`
- ' - `&apos;`

The following should work:

```
XmlElement costCenterElement2 = doc.CreateElement("CostCenter");
costCenterElement2.InnerXml =
  "<CostCenterNumber>2</CostCenterNumber> <CostCenter>" +
  "G&amp;A: Fin &amp; Acctng" +
  "</CostCenter>";
```

However, you really should be creating the `CostCenterNumber` and `CostCenter` as elements and not as `InnerXml`.

Comment: You could also take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468560.aspx for more info.

Comment: thanks oded for your reply but really this string is parse in method parameters and i don't know the string contains & or any special characters I need general to escape all special characters

Comment: actually `>` (greater-than) *is* allowed in XML and doesn't have to be escaped. But many people do escape it, for symmetry. Also, `"` (`&quot;` not `&quote;`) and `'` are fine in text data, as in the given question. They just aren't allowed in attribute values.

Comment: @LarsH - from the spec (XML 1.0, section 2.4): `The right angle bracket (>) may be represented using the string " &gt; ", and MUST, for compatibility, be escaped using either " &gt; " or a character reference when it appears in the string " ]]> " in content, when that string is not marking the end of a CDATA section.`

Comment: Good point... a rare exception when `>` does need be escaped. I would still object, though, to the blanket statement (implication) that `>` "is not valid in XML".

Answer (score 1):

**Updated:**

@thabet, if the string `"<CostCenterNumber>...G&A: Fin & Acctng</CostCenter>"` is coming in as a parameter, and it's supposed to represent XML to be parsed, then it has to be well-formed XML to start with. In the example you gave, it isn't. `&` signals the start of an entity reference, is followed by an entity name, and is terminated by `;`, which never appears in the string above.

If you are given that whole string as a parameter, some of which is markup that must be parsed (i.e. the start/end tags), and some of which may contain markup that should not be parsed (i.e. the `&`), there is no clean and reliable way to "escape" the latter and not escape the former. You could replace all `&` characters with `&amp;`, but in doing so you might accidentally turn `&#160;` into `&amp;#160;` and your resulting content would be wrong. If this is your situation, that you are receiving input "XML" where markup is mixed with unparseable text, the best recourse is to *tell the person from whom you are getting the XML that it's not well-formed and they need to fix their output.* There are ways for them to do that that are not difficult with standard XML tools.

If on the other hand you have

```
<CostCenterNumber>2</CostCenterNumber>
<CostCenter>...</CostCenter>
```

separately from the passed string, and you need to plug in the passed string as the text content of the child `<CostCenter>`, and you know it is not to be parsed (does not contain elements), then you can do this:

- create `<CostCenterNumber>` and `<CostCenter>` as elements
- make them children of the parent `<CostCenter>`
- set CostCenterNumber's text content using InnerXML assuming there is no risk of markup in there: `eltCCN.InnerXml = "2";`
- create for the child CostCenter element a Text node child whose value is the passed string: `textCC = doc.CreateText(argStr)`;
- assign that text node as a child of the child CostCenter element: `eltCC.AppendChild(textCC);`